# Why a nodejs write stream causes an increasingly memory consumption?

Tags: node.js

I'm reading a 45Mb text file in NodeJS and doing some processing to each char on it.

The first version of my script took one char from the original file, store it in an accumulator variable (result += char), and at then end saves result in a text file. This does not work since the file was so big I was putting too much data on RAM, so I got an error: *Javascript Heap out of memory*. I decided to use a write stream so I can write data directly to disk one chat at the time so this could solve the issue:

```
fs = require('fs');

var proportion = 2;

var c = '';

fs.readFile('./concat/all.txt', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }

    var h = parseInt(Math.sqrt(data.length / proportion));
    var w = parseInt(h * proportion);

    console.log(w, h);

    var wstream = fs.createWriteStream('output.txt');


    var lineCount = 0;
    for(var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {

        if(data.charCodeAt(x) === 32 && x > 0 && data.charCodeAt(x - 1) === 32)
            continue;

        if(data.charCodeAt(x) === 10 && x > 0 && data.charCodeAt(x - 1) === 10)
            continue;

        c = (data.charCodeAt(x) === 10 || data.charCodeAt(x) === 13 || data.charCodeAt(x) === 9) ? " " : data.charAt(x);
        lineCount++;
        if(lineCount > w) {
            c += "\n";
            lineCount = 0;
        }


        wstream.write(c);
    }

    wstream.end();

});
```

But still, I'm getting an out of memory error. The script runs with no problems if I comment `wstream.write(c)`. Why?

Comment: i guess because your for-loop finishes in maybe 1 sec and the writing still takes 100 secs. so basically it's still all in memory... you need to slow your `wstream.write(c);` calls down.

Comment: ... i would even say the first char is only written after you exit your readFile callback. and before that all data you want to write is buffered in memory.

Comment: So? Is my solution as **crossplatform** as you wanted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Stream, stream, stream ...

**Throttle the I/O :**

Stream the input in chunks, pause the stream for each chunk, parse & manipulate each character of the current chunk and write it to the output.

Then you may resume the input stream to continue with the next one, repeat until finish.

---

I had no problem with throttling your code using `createReadStream` & `createWriteStream`

Here is the code (tested successfully with a `64MB` file)

```
const fs = require('fs')
var w;  var charCount = 0;  var proportion = 2
//:This step was required to populate 'w'
fs.readFile('input.txt', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
 if(err){return console.log(err)}
 let h = parseInt(Math.sqrt(data.length / proportion))
 w = parseInt(h * proportion); data = undefined;
 console.log('[+] starting  ( w:',w,')'); EMX()
});
//:Here is the magick
function EMX(){
 const I = fs.createReadStream('input.txt')
 const O = fs.createWriteStream('output.txt')
 I.on('end',()=>{console.log("[+] operation completed")})
 I.on('data', (chunk) => {
  I.pause(); let data = chunk.toString()
  for(var x=0;x<data.length;x++){
   if(data.charCodeAt(x) === 32 && x > 0 && data.charCodeAt(x - 1) === 32) continue
   if(data.charCodeAt(x) === 10 && x > 0 && data.charCodeAt(x - 1) === 10) continue
   c = (data.charCodeAt(x) === 10 || data.charCodeAt(x) === 13 || data.charCodeAt(x) === 9) ? " " : data.charAt(x)
   if(charCount>w){c+="\n";charCount=0;} charCount++
   O.write(c)
  }
  I.resume()
 })
}
```